# Azure Blockchain as a Service port's config

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-blockchain-service

I am using Blockchain as a Service on Azure to deploy a private blockchain.

The default ports are `8545` for the `RPC ENDPOINT` and `3000` for the first transaction node. I would like to change these parameters because of a firewall constraint.

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, this is possible. You could use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/ethereum-consortium-blockchain-network) to do this.

Download [`azuredeploy.json`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/ethereum-consortium-blockchain-network/azuredeploy.json#L173) file to your local PC, and modify `adminSitePort`and `gethRPCPort` value you want.

```
"adminSitePort": 3000,

"gethRPCPort": 8545,
```

Then you could use PowerShell to deploy this template.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name <deployment name> -ResourceGroupName <resource group name > -TemplateFile "D:\azuredeploy.json"
```

After the template is deployed successful, you need check Azure NSG that opens port that you need.
[image]